# XCode: Changed Other Linker Flag and now have clang error

Tags: ios, xcode, clang

I was having an issue with Google Maps and someone suggested changing -Objc in our build settings to -ObjC. When I do that I get a build error:

```
linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I am coming into an existing app on this so there is no Test target, it was already removed. That seems to be a popular solution to this issue. If I revert it back to -Objc the app builds but I am getting @selector errors with the Google map instantiation.

[image]

And if someone could explain what (use -v to see invocation) means I'd really appreciate it.

[image]

Comment: The "linker command failed" message is a summary rather than a reason.  Look in the Report Navigator, find the link command that failed, and expand it.  That should give you better details of what happened leading up to that message.

Comment: Maybe I am doing it wrong but there's nothing there except the message I posted. I don't see anything to expand. (see my edit)

Comment: Clicking the icon on the far right of the line that starts "Link /Users..." should show more.  Specifically, it should show which symbols are duplicates.

Comment: I had looked there. It expands with a bunch of duplicate symbol warnings for BugSense and Crittercism but doesn't provide any new details. (see edits again)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's saying that you're trying to link both a BugSense framework and a library from a Crittercism SDK and that they're colliding with each other because both contain a copy of the same .o file.

The reason you're seeing the problem is because -ObjC tells the linker to load all symbols (even if you have duplicates).  To the best of my knowledge, -Objc has no meaning.

Comment: ah, thanks. I thought the Crittcercism and BugSense issues were just warnings.

Comment: That did it. Legacy code [eyeroll]. The app wasn't even using Crittercism anymore.